# Why Is this Property not being updated when I pass it by reference in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

Could somebody please explain why the update to the property is not being persisted after the function exits in the example below

```
function CreateConfigObject
{
    # base solution directory
    $Config = New-Object -typename PSObject

    # Build Config File Contents
    $Config | Add-Member -Name MyProperty -MemberType NoteProperty -Value "Original Value"

    return $Config
}

function MyFunction([ref]$obj)
{
    Write-Host "Inside function Before Updating : " $obj.Value
    Write-host "Are the objects equal? " $obj.Value.Equals($config.MyProperty)

    $obj.Value = "New Value"
    Write-Host "Inside function After Updating : " $obj.Value

}



$config = CreateConfigObject

Write-Host "Before calling function : " $config.MyProperty

MyFunction ([ref]$config.MyProperty)

Write-Host "After calling function : " $config.MyProperty
```

Answer (score 4):

Took a bit of figuring, but I've got an answer. [ref] passes an object, not a value, to a function. So what you would need to do is pass `$config` to the function, and then reference it's value, and the `.MyProperty` property of that value. Look at this slightly altered code to see my point:

```
function CreateConfigObject
{
    # base solution directory
    $Config = New-Object -typename PSObject

    # Build Config File Contents
    $Config | Add-Member -Name MyProperty -MemberType NoteProperty -Value "Original Value"

    return $Config
}

function MyFunction([ref]$obj)
{
    Write-Host "Inside function Before Updating : " $obj.value.MyProperty
    Write-host "Are the objects equal? " $obj.value.MyProperty.Equals($config.MyProperty)

    $obj.value.MyProperty = "New Value"
    Write-Host "Inside function After Updating : " $obj.value.MyProperty

}



$config = CreateConfigObject

Write-Host "Before calling function : " $config.MyProperty

MyFunction ([ref]$config)

Write-Host "After calling function : " $config.MyProperty
```

That will output the expected results:

```
Before calling function :  Original Value
Inside function Before Updating :  Original Value
Are the objects equal?  True
Inside function After Updating :  New Value
After calling function :  New Value
```

Comment: And since you are passing the parent object, you do not need `[ref]` any more.

Comment: @EmperorXLII Right, you don't need it on the function, but it is still required when you call the function for the referenced object. so `MyFunction($obj)` is ok, but you still need `MyFunction ([ref]$config)`

Comment: Sorry, I meant that `[ref]` could be removed from both the function and the call site. You only need `[ref]` to change the target of a variable. For example, if you have `function f($h) { $h['a'] = 'b' }` and a hashtable `$v`, calling `f $v` will add an element to the hashtable without `[ref]` (just as `MyFunction` can set `MyProperty` without using `[ref]`). On the other hand, if you have `function g([ref]$h) { $h.Value = @{ 'c' = 'd' } }` and `$w = $null`, you need to use `g ([ref]$w)` in order to get the result into `$w`.